# Configure debug setting for PETSc in VScode

Tags: petsc

This will be a long shot, but I would like to know if anyone in the community has the .json setting for running PETSc in VScode (for debbuging).

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I am using example 19 from /petsc/src/snes/tutorials as a case.

I made a makefile with:

```
 touch makefile
```

Inside I placed:

```
include ${PETSC_DIR}/lib/petsc/conf/variables
include ${PETSC_DIR}/lib/petsc/conf/rules

example19: example19.o chkopts
    -${CLINKER} -o example19 example19.o ${PETSC_LIB}
        ${RM} example19.o
```

in the `.json` files of vscode

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "preLaunchTask": "run petsc makefile",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And in **tasks.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "run petsc makefile",
            "command": "make",
            "args": [
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
                "env": {"PETSC_DEB":  "/home/pc/petsc"}
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

This creates the executable and runs the script. But I cannot attach the debugger.

Would appreciate some help.

Best Regards

Comment: can anyone give me a hand with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can start a PETSc program, pause it for the debugger, and attach the VS Code debugger.

`launch.json`

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
            "name": "Attach to process",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
            "program": "/dev/null",
            "linux": {
                "MIMode": "gdb"
            },
            "osx": {
                "MIMode": "lldb"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Start the program and have it sleep for 20 seconds so you can attach the debugger:

```
myprogram -stop_for_debugger -pause_debugger=20
```

The `-stop_for_debugger` option will cause the program to print the process id to stdout.

1. In the left sidebar, select "Run and Debug".
2. At the top of the panel, select `Attach to process`.
3. Select the process for `myprogram` that matches the process id printed to stdout when you started the program.

VS Code cppdbg requires a "program", but the value does not matter as long as it exists on the filesystem.